# Returning a OleDbDataReader from a function

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to return `OleDbDataReader` from a function. I search on internet and I found some help and I create a code

```
public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> ImportXLS(string path)
       {

           string connString = "";
           string strFileType = ".xlsx";

           if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
           {
               connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
           }
           else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
           {
               connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
           }

           string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

           OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
           conn.Open();
           OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

           using (IDataReader xlsReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               while (xlsReader.Read())
               {
                   yield return (IDataReader)xlsReader;
               }
           }

           conn.Close();
       }
```

This is OK It Return `xlsReader`, and I try to catch this `xlsReader` by

```
public string UploadFile(string tPath, string FileName)
    {
        string msg = "";

        FileImportModule.FileImport OFileImport = new FileImportModule.FileImport();
        SqlDataReader reader = (SqlDataReader)OFileImport.ImportXLS(tPath);            
        var context = new MountSinaiEntities1();

        string tableName = context.Tables.Find(1).tableName;
        var tableFieldList = from a in context.TablesFields                        
                             where a.tableId == 1
                             select a.fieldName;     

        //1- SQL Bulk Copy
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=abhishek-pc;Initial Catalog=MountSinai;User ID=sa;Password=abhi");
            con.Open();
            SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
            {
                bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                bulkcopy.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           //Handle Exception
        }
   }
```

but the error occur

> Unable to cast object of type 'd__0' to type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'

What is the Solution for that problem? Any alternative to use it as reader object...

Comment: Make `ImportXLS` return a `IDataReader`. Don't forget to close the connections and the readers (use using(...) or `.Close()` in a finally block).

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a type of `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>`, so you cannot cast it to an `SqlDataReader`.

Just return `xlsReader` (making sure to dispose it properly) if that is what you want. Otherwise, just use the data you are returning.